# influxdb count() gives wrong value

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have Influx DB where I store information related jenkins.

when I execute when below query

```sql
SELECT
  project_name,
  build_number,
  build_result
FROM (
  SELECT
    project_name,
    build_number,
    build_result
  FROM
    "jenkins_data"
  WHERE (
    "project_name" =~ /^(?i)(test1|test2)$/ AND
    "project_path" =~ /.*(?i)Playground.*$/
  )
  ORDER BY time DESC
  LIMIT 15
)
WHERE (
  "build_result" = 'SUCCESS'
)
ORDER BY time DESC
```

will get the below result

```
time                project_name         build_number build_result
```

---

```
1676039543717000000 test1                1600         SUCCESS
1676039352721000000 test1                1792         SUCCESS
1676039283509000000 test2                1669         SUCCESS
1676039543717000000 test1                1600         SUCCESS
1676039352721000000 test1                1792         SUCCESS
1676039283509000000 test2                1669         SUCCESS
1676039543717000000 test1                1600         SUCCESS
1676039352721000000 test1                1792         SUCCESS
1676039283509000000 test2                1669         SUCCESS
1676039283509000000 test2                1669         SUCCESS
```

the above result is correct
but when use count in my query it gives improper results

```sql
SELECT
  count(build_number)
FROM (
  SELECT
    project_name,
    build_number,
    build_result
  FROM
    "jenkins_data"
  WHERE (
    "project_name" =~ /^(?i)(test1|test2)$/ AND
    "project_path" =~ /.*(?i)Playground.*$/
  )
  ORDER BY time DESC
  LIMIT 15
)
WHERE (
  "build_result" = 'SUCCESS'
)
ORDER BY time DESC
```

will give result as **15** which is not correct I am doing anything wrong here?

Influxdb version used -  **InfluxDB v1.8.6 (git: 1.8 v1.8.6)**

Comment: What exactly is incorrect about the result? Is the resulting number greater or less of your expected result?

Comment: its grater than expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could able to solve the issue by adding DISTINCT in count functions.

used below query

```sql
SELECT
  count(DISTINCT build_number)
FROM (
  SELECT
    project_name,
    build_number,
    build_result
  FROM
    "jenkins_data"
  WHERE (
    "project_name" =~ /^(?i)(test1|test2)$/ AND
    "project_path" =~ /.*(?i)Playground.*$/
  )
  ORDER BY time DESC
  LIMIT 15
)
WHERE (
  "build_result" = 'SUCCESS'
)
ORDER BY time DESC
```